# How to enforce at least one entry in a params T [] when passed in to a method call?

Tags: c#

Say I had a class like this:

```
public class MyObjectManipulator<T>
{
    void DoStuffWithExpressions( T @object, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expressions );
}
```

I could use it like so:

```
var someObj = new SomeType();
new MyObjectManipulator<SomeType>().DoStuffWithExpressions(someObj, s => s.Name, s => s.Size..);
```

BUT the compiler wont enforce that there need to be be at least one expression passed in. This would compile, but would be completely useless:

```
var someObj = new SomeType();
new MyObjectManipulator<SomeType>().DoStuffWithExpressions(someObj); //'what am I supposed to do with this object?!?'
```

I can check inside the method and throw an exception if the array is null or empty, but I wan't compile time checking. I can change the signature to look like this:

```
public class MyObjectManipulator<T>
{
    void DoStuffWithExpressions( T @object, Expression<Func<T, object>> mandatoryExpression, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] optionalExpressions);
}
```

and then build up a single list inside the method, but that spoils the API.

Besides writing my own code analysis plugin to just manually check, is there a neat way to enforce at compile time that at least one expression must be passed in?

Comment: "spoils the API"? Isn't that exactly the API you want? There's no other compile-time way to do it (without writing a plugin as you suggest).

Comment: Even with the solution given in that possible duplicate, nothing prevents calling with a null value for that parameter. So the method still needs to handle that possibility.